# Get formated time before midnight in bash on Mac OS

Tags: macos, bash

I would like to get time before midnight in bash on Mac OS (which has not the same date utility as many Linux distro).

For example, at 23:56:03 I would like to get : "00:03:59".

Comment: Can you clarify if you want an alternative command to date, and or are you looking to manipulate the returned time for future time calculations? Any examples on what you have tried/works else where would be a help.

Comment: I would like to know how to get my example working, it's just for displaying in GeekTools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSX Does have the date command

see - [OSX Date man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html)

To get just the time use:

```
date +"%T"
```

You need to use some **BASIC** maths

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
hours=`date +"%H"`
minutes=`date +"%M"`
seconds=`date +"%S"`
# Time till midnight
echo `expr 23 - ${hours}`" hours, "`expr 59 - ${minutes}`" minutes, and "`expr 59 - ${seconds}`" seconds "
```

Comment: Yes, but it's not the same program that can be found on Debian or Red Hat

Comment: Yes, it would be based on the BSD date command as OSX inherits substantial portions.

Comment: Thanks, but I know this command, I'm just looking for to fulfill a need described above.

Comment: Read the question : I would like the time before midnight.

Comment: Let `bash` do the arithmetic instead of shelling out to `expr`; this question is already specific to a single implementation of `date`, so I wouldn't worry about making it POSIX-compatible as well. `echo "$((24-hours)) hours, $((60-minutes)) minutes, and $((60-seconds)) seconds"`.

Comment: I've accepted your answer but I've made a small edit to fix these basic maths. Finally I used @chepner suggestion but yours works fine too.

Comment: Say it's 23:30. As written, this code will claim it is 1 hour and 30 minutes to midnight. You can't simply subtract each component separately.

Comment: I've tried to fixed it in an edit that doesn't appear (maybe it's been refused)

Answer (score 2):

The math is a little easier to do if you work with Unix timestamps, which are the number of elapsed seconds from some fixed time in the past (Jan 1, 1970). I use the `local` built-in to make them local to the function, as well as to set the integer attribute of the variables, since it makes the syntax for doing arithmetic simpler.

```
print_time_until_midnight () {
  local -i now=$(date +%s)

  if (( now % 86400 == 0 )); then
      # If it is exactly midnight, say so
      echo "Time remaining: 00:00:00"
      return
  fi

  # Get the time for 00:00:00 *tomorrow* (the next midnight)
  local -i midnight=$(date -v+1d -v0H -v0M -v0S +%s)

  local -i S=midnight-now
  local -i H=S/3600
  S=S-H*3600

  local -i M=S/60
  S=S-M*60

  echo "Time remaining: $H:$M:$S"
}
```